# Interpreting the CSS 3 font matching algorithm

Tags: css, fonts, gecko, blink

The [CSS 3 Font Matching Algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-style-matching) states

> **4. a.** `‘font-stretch’` is tried first. If the matching set contains faces with width values matching the `‘font-stretch’` value, faces with other width values are removed from the matching set. If there is no face that exactly matches the width value the nearest width is used instead. If the value of `‘font-stretch’` is `‘normal’` or one of the condensed values, narrower width values are checked first, then wider values. If the value of `‘font-stretch’` is one of the expanded values, wider values are checked first, followed by narrower values. Once the closest matching width has been determined by this process, faces with other widths are removed from the matching set.

How do you interpret the spec's ordering combined with "closest matching width"?

Say that the available widths are

- `semi-expanded` (112.5%)
- `ultra-expanded` (200%)

If the page requests `font-stretch: expanded` (125%), the spec says to look at wider values first, then narrower values. So would the selected width end up being `ultra-expanded` because it's *wider* than `expanded`, or `semi-expanded` because it's *closer* to `expanded`?

Or, to take a more extreme case, if the two available widths are

- `ultra-condensed` (50%)
- `semi-expanded` (112.5%)

and `font-stretch: normal` (100%) is requested, which would the algorithm select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [3.3. Font width: the font-stretch property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-stretch-prop)

> When a face does not exist for a given width, normal or condensed values map to a narrower face, otherwise a wider face. Conversely, expanded values map to a wider face, otherwise a narrower face.

The only interpretation of the algorithm which is consistent with that statement is:

For the first case: "the nearest wider face if any, otherwise the nearest narrower face."
 i.e. `ultra-expanded`

For the second case: "the nearest narrower face if any, otherwise the nearest wider face."
 i.e. `ultra-condensed`